# Rackspace cloud files return "application/unknown" as mime-type when uploaded with Jclouds

Tags: mime-types, content-type, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, jclouds

Basically I have this code which uploads javascripts and other content to Rackspace using [Jclouds](http://jclouds.apache.org/):

```
SwiftObject obj = cloudFilesClient.newSwiftObject();
obj.getInfo().setName(name);
obj.getInfo().setContentType(contentType);
obj.setPayload(payloadFile);
cloudFilesClient.putObject(container, obj);
```

I noticed that Chrome complains about scripts being transferred with `text/plain` and so set out to investigate. `curl -I` report instead: `Content-Type: application/unknown`.

I've Googled a lot and tried to find some clues, and I've tried:

- not setting content type at all
- setting empty string (found some rumour about that somewhere)
- setting to `application/javascript` (correct)
- setting to `text/javascript` (wrong, but common)
- `obj.getAllHeaders().put("Content-Type", contentType);`

When we used to upload with basic HTTP before, this just worked without setting anything manually at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally finally managed to figure it out by digging in the source code - this works:

```
FilePayload payload = new FilePayload(uploadableFile.localPath.toFile());
payload.getContentMetadata().setContentType(uploadableFile.contentType);
obj.setPayload(payload);
```

In case anyone else is looking for this in the future, posting Q&A.

Comment: do you have a working version of JClouds that fixes this or an example of how to fix my version. Thanks.

Comment: @Josh that example in the answer was what worked for me at the time of writing it. A bit later, we ditched Rackspace for other reasons and so I'm not in the loop anymore. Sorry!